# How can I reduce MYSQL usage when sorting this index for a Wordpress site?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, hosting

I received a note from Hostgator indicating that they've restricted my access to MYSQL because my site is using too many resources.

Normally, in a case like this, I'd just restore a backup to see if I recent change was producing the error. But, I haven't made any recent changes--apart from writing a few new posts.

Here's the report Hostgator included with their note--with my personal details removed:

> Running Queries:
>
> *************************** 1. row ***************************
>
> USER: xxx_wrdp1
>
> DB: xxx_wrdp1
>
> STATE: Creating sort index
>
> TIME: 1
>
> COMMAND: Query
>
> INFO: SELECT l.ID, post_title, post_content, post_name, post_parent,
>   post_author, post_status, post_modified_gmt, post_date, post_date_gmt
>
> ```
>   FROM (   SELECT wp_posts.ID
> ```
>
> FROM wp_posts
>
> ```
>   WHERE wp\_posts.post\_status IN ('publish')   AND
> ```
>
> wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
>
> AND wp_posts.post_password = ''
>
> AND wp_posts.post_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
>
> ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified ASC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 142200
>
> ```
>   )  
>
>   o JOIN wp\_posts l ON [l.ID](https://l.ID) = [o.ID](https://o.ID)
> ```

If any can offer a suggestion on what's causing this the uptick in resource usage (or how it can be remedied), I'd be curious.

Thanks!

Comment: `ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified ASC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 142200` -> `LIMIT 100 OFFSET 142200` limits with big offset is a no go when when idnexes correctly .. As MySQL needs to store 142300  records in memory to remove 142200 again to give the 100 as result.

Comment: ideally you  need do  `WHERE id >= 142200 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified ASC LIMIT 100`  and keep track off your pages.. Where the other run becomes `WHERE id >= 142300 ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified ASC LIMIT 100` ..  But not sure if this is possible with your data as id needs to be auto_incremented..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks for pointing this out. Can recommend a fix?

Comment: *"Can recommend a fix?"* See mine last comment?

Comment: @RaymondNijland I think I understand the queries you've suggested. And, I could use them in place of the queries from the report above. But, I didn't run the queries in the report above. Is it possible they were run by a plugin or automated process?

Answer (score 0):

Why that query has an inner select from the same table? Is there a specific purpose? (I extracted the query from report you posted)

```
SELECT
    l.ID,
    post_title,
    post_content,
    post_name,
    post_parent,
    post_author,
    post_status,
    post_modified_gmt,
    post_date,
    post_date_gmt

FROM (
    SELECT
        wp_posts.ID
    FROM wp_posts
    WHERE wp_posts.post_status IN ('publish')
      AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
      AND wp_posts.post_password = ''
      AND wp_posts.post_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified ASC
) o
JOIN wp_posts l
  ON l.ID = o.ID
```

If that was the case, i'd change the query to:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    post_title,
    post_content,
    post_name,
    post_parent,
    post_author,
    post_status,
    post_modified_gmt,
    post_date,
    post_date_gmt
FROM wp_posts
WHERE wp_posts.post_status IN ('publish')
  AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
  AND wp_posts.post_password = ''
  AND wp_posts.post_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_modified ASC
```

In this late example, you need to run the query with the EXPLAIN tag to check in which table/column it would require a proper index (usually when it says that rows count are bigger than 1).

Comment: I'd be happy to test the query you suggested, but I didn't run the query in the error report above. Is it possible it was run by a plugin or automated process?